# Python- Using dictionaries to compare two lists

Tags: list, python-2.7, dictionary

Newbie to Python. i have been asked to write a function sameVowels(s1, s2), that given 2 strings s1,s2, returns True if both strings have exactly the same vowels (kind and number).
(Think how to use dictionaries..)

I tried this:

```
import string
def sameVowels( s1 , s2 ) :
   d1 = {}
   d2 = {}
   vowels = [ 'a' , 'e' , 'i' , 'o' , 'u' ]

   for v1 in s1 :
      for k1 in vowels :
        if v1 == k1 :
            d1[k1] = v1

   for v2 in s2 :
      for k2 in vowels :
        if v2 == k2 :
            d2[k2] = v2
print d1
print d2
return d1 == d2

print sameVowels( 'aabcefiok' , 'xcexvcxaioa' )
print sameVowels( 'aabcefiok' , 'xcexvcxaioia' )
```

**but what I get is:**

```
{'a': 'a', 'i': 'i', 'e': 'e', 'o': 'o'}
{'a': 'a', 'i': 'i', 'e': 'e', 'o': 'o'}
True
{'a': 'a', 'i': 'i', 'e': 'e', 'o': 'o'}
{'a': 'a', 'i': 'i', 'e': 'e', 'o': 'o'}
True
```

**the last pair should give False because the second string has an extra "i"**
I really dont know how to do it
please help :)

Comment: You're importing, but not using, the `string` module. Get rid of that import ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to store pairs like `{vowel : ocurrences}`, so try modifying the logic in your 2 `for` statements:

```
for v1 in s1 : # Iterate over string1
    if v1 in vowels: # Check if each letter is a vowel
        if v1 in d1: # If the vowel is in dict1
            d1[v1] += 1 # Add 1 to the actual value
        else: 
            d1[v1] = 1 # Add the vowel to dict1
```

The same for the second `for`:

```
for v2 in s2 :
    if v2 in vowels:
        if v2 in d2:
            d2[v2] += 1
        else:
            d2[v2] = 1
```

Comment: I didn't understand this line:
<if v1 in vowels: # Check if each letter is a vowel>
Because the dictionaries are empty..the letter is not in dict1

Comment: You loop over string `s1`, so `v1` is a letter each iteration. That line just check if the letter `v1` is a vowel, technically it checks if `v1` is an element of the list `vowels`. It's **not** related with dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

A somewhat simpler though less performant version (since we're counting each letter):

```
def sameVowels(s1,s2):
    vowels = [ 'a' , 'e' , 'i' , 'o' , 'u' ]
    f1 = dict((letter, s1.count(letter)) for letter in vowels)
    f2 = dict((letter, s2.count(letter)) for letter in vowels)
    return f1==f2
```

Another option:

```
from collections import Counter
def sameVowels(s1,s2):
    vowels = [ 'a' , 'e' , 'i' , 'o' , 'u' ]
    filtered1 = filter(lambda x: x in vowels, s1)
    filtered2 = filter(lambda x: x in vowels, s2)
    f1 = Counter(filtered1)
    f2 = Counter(filtered2)
    return f1==f2
```